# How can I pass a function as a prop to 2 nested/child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this parent component:

**filtersModal.js**

```
// imports

class FiltersModal extends React.Component {
  state = { carrier: '' };

  applyFilters = () => {
    const { carrier } = this.state;
    applyFilters({ carrier });
  };

  handleChange = field => ev => {
    this.setState({ [field]: ev.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        open={isFiltersModalOpened}
        onRequestSubmit={this.applyFilters}
      >
        <Form>
           <GetAllCouriers handleCouriers={this.handleChange('carrier')} />
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

FiltersModal.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isFiltersModalOpened: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleFiltersModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  applyFilters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(FiltersModal);
```

And also I have this other component which is a child of the above one:

**getAllCouriers.js**

```
// other imports
import CouriersSelect from '../CouriersSelect';

const GetAllCouriers = ({ t, softlayerAccountId, handleCouriers }) => (
  <Query query={GET_ALL_COURIERS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      let getAllCouriers;

      if (data && data.GetAllCouriers) {
        getAllCouriers = data.GetAllCouriers;
      }

      return (
        <CouriersSelect
          allCouriersList={getAllCouriers}
          onChange={handleCouriers}
        />
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);

GetAllCouriers.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  softlayerAccountId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default compose(
  connect(store => ({
    softlayerAccountId: store.global.softlayerAccountId,
  })),
  translate(),
)(GetAllCouriers);
```

And this is the component which is a child of the right above one that contains the `onChange` function handling the prop `handleCouriers`

**couriersSelect.js**

```
// imports

const CouriersSelect = ({ t, handleCouriers, allCouriersList }) => (
  <Select onChange={handleCouriers}>
    {allCouriersList.map(carriers => (
      <SelectItem
        key={carriers.name}
        value={carriers.name}
        text={carriers.name}
      />
    ))}
  </Select>
);

CouriersSelect.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  allCouriersList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})).isRequired,
  handleCouriers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(CouriersSelect);
```

I have some different components where I need to pass the `handleChange` function on `FiltersModal.js`

```
  handleChange = field => ev => {
    this.setState({ [field]: ev.target.value });
  };
```

One of these components is `getAllCouriers.js`, I need to make it to work there. As you see, `getAllCouriers.js` is called on `filtersModal.js` but the `onChange` function is present on `couriersSelect.js`. So this function has to travel from `couriersSelect.js` which is a child of `getAllCouriers.js` and `getAllCouriers.js` is a child of `filtersModal.js`.

What can I do?

Comment: I would recommend you to look into `redux`, it will help you avoid passing data in such ways. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Keep you function in top most component and Pass function like this:

```
<GetAllCouriers handleCouriers={() => this.handleChange('carrier')} />
```

Hope this answered your questions